# Updating just won't work

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, razor

I am trying to update my table. I have a page with just one TextBox where the user can enter a quantity, but it just doesn't update. There's no errors or anything. And, let's just say that there was already '1' in the column, and then I update it to say, '6', then I go back to the table, that particular row has now become '0'. I don't get it.

When I look at the Query String part of the url.. No matter what value I post ufing the form, it always says 0 is the query string.

Here's what I've got:

```
    var UpdateQuantityQuery = "";
    if(Request.Form["IsBoxed"].AsBool() == true)
    {
        UpdateQuantityQuery = "UPDATE Cart SET Boxes = '" + Request.Form["quantity"].AsInt() + "' WHERE PartNumber = '" + Request.Form["PartNumber"] + "' AND IsBoxed = 'True' AND OrderId = '" + Session["OSFOID"] + "'";
        database.Execute(UpdateQuantityQuery);

        // Redirect back to their SHopping Cart now.
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Cart.cshtml");
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateQuantityQuery = "UPDATE Cart SET Units = '" + Request.Form["quantity"].AsInt() + "' WHERE PartNumber = '" + Request.Form["PartNumber"] + "' AND IsBoxed = 'False' AND OrderId = '" + Session["OSFOID"] + "'";
        database.Execute(UpdateQuantityQuery);

        // Redirect back to their SHopping Cart now.
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Cart.cshtml");
    }
```

And the form code is:

```
<form method="post" action="EditQuantity.cshtml?Update=OK&PartNumber=@Request["PartNumber"]&IsBoxed=@Request["IsBoxed"]">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Quantity</legend>
        <label for="quantity">
                @Message
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" title="Edit Quantity" />
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" title="Confirm Change" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong here that could be causing this to cojombulate?

Comment: Print the `UpdateQuantityQuery` , too, to see what exactly is sent to the database. What does `.AsInt()` do?

Comment: Not answering your question, but looking at your code, you might want to read up on SQL Injection attacks and how to avoid them.  The way you're writing your queries is the textbook example of how NOT to use user input in an SQL query. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: I'd like to submit a form post with parameter "PartNumber" as `';DROP TABLE CART` Your code is HIGHLY vulnerable to SQL injection. Look up parameterized queries with some urgency.

Comment: Did you try writing the query without any variables and executing just to see that your connecting to the correct database and everything is ok ? Or perhaps writing the query in SQL Server Management Studio and executing to see if it works?

Comment: The SQL-Server expects the number in decimal notation, like `UPDATE Cart SET Units = 6`

Comment: PLEASE if you're writing a shopping cart application that is actually going to be used, visit the OWASP web site at http://www.owasp.org and spend a great deal of time researching secure coding techniques before going any further.  Better yet,  Buy a commercial cart. The cost of a quality commercial cart is much less than the cost of having your customer's identity stolen.

Comment: @ypercube - I think what you're saying is it is suggesting a value without the single quotes? I just changed that, still isn't working.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your concerns and advice. I am building an inventory management app, with a cart in it, but won't be used in the real world. Hence why I haven't bothered with any security stuff. I'm just playing around/learning to try and get the hang of all this Webatrix/Razor stuff before I do any real world stuff.

Comment: @ypercube - I just printed the UpdateQuantityQuery, and this is how it reads: `UPDATE Cart SET Units = 5 WHERE PartNumber = '' AND IsBoxed = 0 AND OrderId = 'V7DzbMqR'`  - So it looks like PartNumber is always empty, so it can't find a matching partnumber in the table which is why it isn't updating?

Comment: Solved. I removed quotes from IsBoxed, and changed IsBoxed values to 0 and 1 instead of true/false, then I changed Request.Form["PartNumber"] and Request.Form["IsBoxed"] to Request.QueryString["IsBoxed"] and Request.QueryString["PartNumber"] - Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Thank you for all the SQL Injection advices and the link, will come in real handy when/if I ever make this into a real world app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
if(Request.QueryString["IsBoxed"].AsBool() == true)
```

not form, you are sending this info through query string not as form element

Comment: Argh. I hope you're not encouraging DB updates on the back of a GET request? Sending change data via query string is a big no no. The real answer is to change the request to be a post, not to use a query string.

Comment: +1.  This is probably the right answer as to why the update is not executing.  However, even this is a horribly bad idea.  It's so easy to tamper with a query string.  Not that creating a form to post to his from from another server would be hard, but at least it's a LITTLE more work to tamper with form post variables than with query string variables.

Comment: Sniffing URLs is considerably easier than sniffing the payloads transferred by form post. URLs are routinely logged all over the web... we don't want user data to pop up in these logs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys, I am making those changes now and will see how it goes.

Comment: @spender - I agree.  I'm thinking strictly about tampering and getting at the data in a badly written app once it's been identified. The mere fact that it uses QueryString parameters in this way makes it that much easier to identify  as a probable easy target for malicious users for exactly the reasons you posted.

Comment: @Senad - thank you but I just changed it from Request.Form to Request.QueryString, but it still doesn't update.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but could it be that in your update queries you're updating integer types with strings? It seems that you're wrapping the values you're casting to integers in single quotes. I guess it all depends on how the types are defined in the database. If they're defined as integers try removing the single quotes. If they are defined as strings then there is not reason to cast them to integers. Just a guess.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that could be it, I am checking that out now. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: thank you - but I just changed it and removed the quotes around quantity - but it still doesn't update.

Comment: Did you take the single quotes out around the IsBoxed = 'True'. If IsBoxed is defined as a bit type this may not work either.

Comment: when I remove the single quotes around IsBoxed, (I have added a try/catch statement to all my code) it outputs an error saying: Invalid column name 'False'.